# Two overloaded methods for printing the same array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently working on an exercise to do the following:

1. Creates a method that fills an [x] by [x] array with random integers. (done)
2. Creates two overloaded methods for printing the array. One prints the loaded array, and the other prints the sorted & loaded array.
3. Use the main method which is to :
   a. Create the array (done)
   b. Calls the method to load the array (done)
   c. Calls the method to print the array(done)
   d. Calls the method to print the sorted array(done)

I cannot figure out how in the world to create an overloaded method that prints a loaded array and a sorted array at once, so maybe I am confused, but I would appreciate any amount of help to decipher this problem.

I have researched this for the past 3 hours, 30 minutes spent on creating the code and doing this entire exercise except for the past 2.5 hours trying to do instruction # 2.

```
// method to print the loaded array
public static void printarray(int [][] arr)
{
  System.out.println("Loaded Array \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
        System.out.print(arr[i][j] +  " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    }

}
// method to print the sorted array
   public static void printarraySorted(int [] [] arr)
{
  System.out.println("Loaded and Sorted Array \n");
   for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
       Arrays.sort(arr[i]);
       System.out.print(arr[i][j] +  " ");
   }
  System.out.println();
   }
}
```

I get the same output, but am still mega-confused about what instruction number 2 is.

Comment: Please move the statement `Arrays.sort(arr[i]);` out of the `j` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding a method can be done by either change the type, sequence or number of parameters.

I would propose doing it the following (changing the number of parameters):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = new int[3][3];
    printArray(arr);
    printArray(arr, true);
  }

  // method to print the loaded array
  public static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
    printArray(arr, false);
  }

  // method to print the sorted array
  public static void printArray(int[][] arr, boolean sort) {
    System.out.println("Loaded and Sorted Array \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (sort) {
        Arrays.sort(arr[i]);
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
```

Comment: This helped me a lot actually, I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: This code is not efficient. `Arrays.sort(arr[i])` should not be done in the `j-loop` but before it. Like it is now, the array gets sorted 9 times instead of 3 times. Also, the initial array is not initialized with values and the `new` keyword is missing. @BlakeBailey, i posted a new answer with the correct code. I don't have the permissions to edit this post unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I just took over the code from the thread opener. But now it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put method overloading in Java means that class can have functions with the same name, but with different parameters list. That's why your task requires to implement 2 functions, for example:

```
static void printArray(int[][] loaded) {
    // TODO
}

static void printArray(int[][] loaded, int[][] sorted) {
    // TODO
}
```

You can read more about overloading [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Comment: Probably you should say parameter list, not argument list. You provide arguments when calling the method, however when speaking about the method declaration generally the term parameter is used.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution that works:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = { { 2, 3, 1 }, { 9, 8, 7 }, { 5, 6, 4 } };
        System.out.println("Unsorted array:");
        printArray(arr);
        System.out.println("Sorted array:");
        printArray(arr, true);
    }

    // method to print the loaded array
    public static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
        printArray(arr, false);
    }

    // method to print the sorted array
    public static void printArray(int[][] arr, boolean sort) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (sort)
                Arrays.sort(arr[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

There are 2 methods with the same name and same parameter list, which means that the method `printArray` is overloaded.

The `i-loop` iterates over all 1-dimensional arrays and sorts those. So, in our case, with a 2-dimensional array of size `3,3` `Arrays.sort` is called 3 times, because there are 3 1-dimensional arrays contained. If we had a 2-dimensional array of size `5,3`, `Arrays.sort` would get called 5 times. The `j-loop` iterates over each element of the whole array and prints its value.